# How to stop scheduledtask running when foreground app is active windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, scheduled-tasks

I've posted previously about synchronisation issues with my background scheduled task having to access a SQLite DB and IsolatedStorge that the foreground app uses.

To simplify the process I thought about just preventing my background task from running altogther, it isn't imperative that it runs, especially when the foreground app is active.

Is there a way to do this?

I thought about using IsolatedStorage to set a flag when the app launches then remove it when it exits, then have the background task check the setting, protected by mutex.

I think the idea is fine in principle, but I guess there will be times when the flag isn't unset, for example if the battery dies... Which means potentially, after turning the phone on, if the user never uses the app and exits properly, the background task will never run. This might not be too much of an issue.

Is using some kind of flag like this the only way to achieve such functionality?

Thanks

Comment: The other problem is that the background task could be running when the user opens the app, so not only do you need a flag to signal that the background task can run, the background task needs its own flag to represent that is is currently busy. If it is busy then make the user wait when they're opening or activating the app (will be max 25 seconds). Does anyone have any other ideas or experience with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inter process communication mechanism to achieve this functionality.
As both the foreground app and scheduletask run as different processes, IPC could be used for it.

Please refer to [Named Events](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/).

In your OnInvoke Method subscribe for a named event which will be fired by your foreground app as soon as it is launched/resumed.

As soon as you get a signal via this event in background agent, just call NotifyComplete and you are done.